# Generating a random Gaussian double in Objective-C/C

Tags: objective-c, c, random, gaussian

I'm trying to generate a random Gaussian double in Objective-C (the same as `random.nextGaussian` in Java). However `rand_gauss()` doesn't seem to work. Anyone know a way of achieving this?

Comment: Pity you didn't ask while I was at work, I looked it up and wrote one a couple months ago.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This link](http://www.taygeta.com/random/gaussian.html) shows how to calculate it using the standard `random()` function.

I should note that you'll likely have to make the `ranf()` routine that converts the output of `random()` from `[0,MAX_INT]` to be from `[0,1]`, but that shouldn't be too difficult.

From the linked article:

> The polar form of the Box-Muller transformation is both faster and more robust numerically. The algorithmic description of it is:
>            float x1, x2, w, y1, y2;

```
     do {
             x1 = 2.0 * ranf() - 1.0;
             x2 = 2.0 * ranf() - 1.0;
             w = x1 * x1 + x2 * x2;
     } while ( w >= 1.0 );

     w = sqrt( (-2.0 * ln( w ) ) / w );
     y1 = x1 * w;
     y2 = x2 * w;
```

Comment: For `randf` use the `drand48()` function. It returns a double in the interval [0, 1). See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/drand48.3.html

Comment: Also use the the `log()` function to take the natural log, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/log